# OpenCart: Requested database data is not showing, but number of rows is correct?

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, opencart

Using OpenCart 3.0.3.8 (default installation) I am creating a dashboard extension but running into an issue. I have no clue what to look for anymore so I was hoping somebody would see what is wrong here. My database query results are not showing on my TWIG template. For each database record an HTML table row is showing, implying the query works, but the data that is supposed to display in the HTML table is not showing. Any pointing in the right direction is very much appreciated! Where did I go wrong?

`tasks.php` **controller:** This function loads the model file and runs a method that queries the database for tasks, from that model file. Then sends the result data to the view/TWIG file.

```
public function dashboard() {
    $this->load->language('extension/dashboard/tasks');

    $data['user_token'] = $this->session->data['user_token'];

    // List tasks
    $data['tasks'] = array();

    $this->load->model('extension/dashboard/tasks');
    
    $results = $this->model_extension_dashboard_tasks->getTasks();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['tasks'][] = array(
            'task_id'                   => $result['task_id'],
            'task_description'  => $result['task_description'],
            'task_status'           => $result['task_status'],
            'task_deadline'         => $result['task_deadline'],
        );
    }

    return $this->load->view('extension/dashboard/tasks_info', $data);
}
```

`tasks.php` **model:** The getTasks() method uses a query that selects all tasks from the 'dashboard_tasks' table, which contains all the tasks, and returns the database records.

```
public function getTasks() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "dashboard_tasks` ORDER BY task_deadline ASC;";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

`tasks_info.twig` **view:** Is supposed to show the data sent by the controller file, but doesn't. For each database record (task) a row is created, and the number of rows is correct. I have 3 tasks in my database and 3 HTML table rows are showing. However, the actual data is missing.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left">{{ column_status }}</td>
      <td class="text-left">{{ column_task }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{ column_deadline }}</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% if tasks %}
      {% for task in tasks %}
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">
            <select name="dashboard_tasks_task_status" id="input-task-status" class="form-control">
              {% if tasks.task_status == 2 %}
                <option value="2" selected="selected">{{ text_task_completed }}</option>
                <option value="1">{{ text_task_pending }}</option>
                <option value="0">{{ text_task_inactive }}</option>
              {% elseif tasks.task_status == 1 %}
                <option value="2">{{ text_task_completed }}</option>
                <option value="1" selected="selected">{{ text_task_pending }}</option>
                <option value="0">{{ text_task_inactive }}</option>
              {% elseif tasks.task_status == 0 %}
                <option value="2">{{ text_task_completed }}</option>
                <option value="1">{{ text_task_pending }}</option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected">{{ text_task_inactive }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="text-left">
            {% if tasks.task_description %}
              {{ tasks.task_description }}
            {% else %}
              {{ text_no_description }}
            {% endif %}
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            {% if tasks.task_deadline %}
              {{ tasks.task_deadline }}
            {% else %}
              {{ text_no_deadline }}
            {% endif %}
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" colspan="4">{{ text_no_tasks }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can debug you code,  try to print the array before you send it to the view, also one thing i notice - i think there is an extra loop to get the data from the DB and send it to an array and then send it to the view, you can select specific required fields from the DB which you need on the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I `var_dump` my `$data['tasks']` array, the array is filled with the right data. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: here is the issue - i guess, when you run you loop you wrote  {{ tasks.task_description }}
 which should be  {{ task.task_description }} ( while printing the value )

Comment: @DebasisRath Oh wow, embarassing. It was just a simple typo I overlooked... Thank you a lot!

Comment: welcome n all the best :)